# Next day check by using calendar JSF primefaces

Tags: date, jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

i am working on a requirement. what i need to do is to retreieve the last enetered date from database, increment it and then check if the day is saturday or not.
the part i am stuck at is how to check if the next day is saturday i am using primefaces 3.5 jsf2.1 apache tomcat 7.0.39

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map requestMap = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String value = (String) requestMap.get("id");
    Integer id = Integer.parseInt(value);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat();
    String sector=new String();
    setFund(new Fund());
    for(Map row:fund_grid){
        Integer edit_id=(Integer.parseInt((String) row.get("fund_id")));
        if(id.equals(edit_id)){
            sector=(String) row.get("fund_sector_label");
            mfp.setFund_id(Integer.parseInt( (String) row.get("fund_id")));
            fund.setFund_id( (String) row.get("fund_id"));
            setValidity_date(request_invoker.select_validity_date());
            try {
                Date ndate=sdf.parse((String) getValidity_date().get(0).get("validitydate"));
```

// Date is here retireved from database value 15-11-2013

//now incrementing for a day

```
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(ndate);
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                fund.setNav_entry_date(c.getTime());
```

//here is where i am stuck i dont know how to check whether date is of saturday or not

```
            if(fund.getNav_entry_date().equals(Calendar.SATURDAY))
                {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
                fund.setNav_entry_date(c.getTime());
                }
                else
                {
                    fund.setNav_entry_date(c.getTime());

                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    RequestContext context2 = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if(sector.equals("open-end")){

        context2.execute("opendialog.show();");
        }
    else if(sector.equals("close-end")){
        context2.execute("closedialog.show();");
        }
    else if(sector.equals("pension")){
        context2.execute("pensiondialog.show();");
        }

}
```

any help much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Made changes to the bean and it works calendar c has the date from database and d has the curret date.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                c.setTime(ndate);

                Calendar d=Calendar.getInstance();  

                if(d.get(Calendar.DATE)==(c.get(Calendar.DATE)))
                {
                    //message here
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("NAV Upto Date" , "NAV Upto Date");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                    break;
                }

                else
                {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                int day=c.SATURDAY;
                int week=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
                if(day==(week))
                {
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, 2);
                fund.setNav_entry_date(c.getTime());
                mfp.getDc().setValiditydate(c.getTime());
                }
                else
                {
                    fund.setNav_entry_date(c.getTime());
                    mfp.getDc().setValiditydate(c.getTime());   
                }
                RequestContext context2 = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
                if(sector.equals("open-end")){

                    context2.execute("openenddialog.show();");
                    }
                else if(sector.equals("close-end")){
                    context2.execute("closeenddialog.show();");
                    }
                else if(sector.equals("pension")){
                    context2.execute("pensiondialog.show();");
                    }
            }
```

Comment: another mistake made by me in the question was that the if condition was matching date v/s integer which is why it kept failing